# HashMap implementation for DHCP fingerprints

Tags: c++, hashmap

I am implementing Hash Map in  C++. I am new to C++. I have to store Values like this.

Motorola = 01 33 03 06 15 26 28 51 58 59

Windows Phone = 01 15 03 06 44 47 31 33 121 249 252 43

I have nearly 50000 such values. 
How  can I implement this?

Comment: Why do you want to implement your own? Use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: i have to implement DHCP fingerprint for each device

Comment: OK, that explains it. Carry on.

Comment: I  still don't understand why unordered map would not work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::map` for this intent.

```
std::map<string, vector<int> > map_Data;
```

In here, each map element consist of a pair of `string` and a `vector <int>`.

```
string --> vector<int>
```

Then you have to first create a `vector` of integers before adding to the `map`. If you don't have an application of constantly searching the values, you even may use a `string` as the value (But it have it's own downsides since storing `string`s is costly than `int`s.).

Then it would look like :

```
std::map<string, string > map_Data;
```

And it of course it depends on your application and the way you read data.
You can implement this as your own hash map using an array of lists. But it will complicate things.

EDIT :

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<std::string, vector<int> > data;

    // assign data
    return 0;
}
```

Refer this link on adding data to vector : 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: What is vector <int> ?

Comment: If you are asking what is a `vector`, it's a dynamic sized container for different type of elements (but one type at a time). In here, the `vector` is used to store your integer values. You may use an array, but as the number of elements differ for different names, it may complicate things.

Comment: Add `#include <map>`, `#include <vector>` and `#include <string>`

And `using namespace std;`

Comment: # include <map> #include<iostream>#include<vector> int main() { std :: map>std:: string, vector<int>> data;data[motorola] = { 10,20,22.43}; return 0;} its my code its  giving me vector is not defined as error

Comment: I think you should get the idea by now. If not, I assume that you have no idea about C++.

Comment: @PavanBilagi : Solved your problem?

Comment: add `using namespace std;` before `main`.

Comment: #include <map> #include<vector> using namespaces std; int main (){ map>string, vector<int> >data; data["M"] = {10,20,30}; return 0; } its my code but this also giving me error as expected primary expression before'{'

Comment: Then read a book and learn the basics of c++. If you don't know what a vector is or how you can use standard library classes in your code I very much doubt that you will be able to implement a proper hashmap

Answer (score 0):

I see you are just starting with C++.

Here's a broad overview of what you would need to implement this yourself :

1) Since you know the size beforehand, and you're not so familiar with vectors, consider using an array of predetermined size.(This will serve as your Map)

2) Now, you have 2 strings to store, corresponding to a key and a value pair.

3) You need to decide what's the key, depending on which value is unique in the pair(Think)

4) Coming to the implementation details, you simply wouldn't store the key(string) as it is. You'd need to hash it. To hash it, you need a hash function. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)
   A common function is to use the ascii value of each character, 
multiplied by it's place value in base 256 (ASCII);'
 modulo a large prime number ~~ size of your Array.
  Why so? (Read on the link! Don't just blindly follow it, you're learning, not hacking :) )

5)Now, how really do hash maps work? This value you just hashed returns an INT, which corresponds to the INDEX of your array, where the VALUE of the corresponding KEY (which we just HASHED to get INDEX) is stored.

Sounds good?

Let me know if you need help!